# Put data from one topic into a dynamic array in the Callback function and do some calculation

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, callback, ros

I am reading my hand pose from a Leap Motion sensor and I want to calculate how fast the hand moves (by calculating `derivativex = dx / dt`) in `X` direction. My solution is to put 100 hand pose values in an array and keep updating this array with new values when new messages (`msg->palmpos.x`) arrive in the callback function through topic `leapmotion/data`.

My question is when I print the `derivativex = dx / dt` with `ROS_ERROR("Hello %f", "derivativex")` the output is always: 0

what I've been doing wrong? [link](https://github.com/ros-drivers/leap_motion/blob/hydro/scripts/sender.py) for the topic that my callback is listening.

my call back function:

```
#include "geometry_msgs/TwistStamped.h"
#include "jog_msgs/JogJoint.h"
#include "jog_msgs/leapros.h"
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include <ros/console.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

namespace to_twist
{
class spaceNavToTwist
{
public:
  spaceNavToTwist() : spinner_(1)


{
    joy_sub_ = n_.subscribe("leapmotion/data", 1, &spaceNavToTwist::joyCallback, this);
    // Changed "spacenav/joy" to topic "/leapmotion/data"
    twist_pub_ = n_.advertise<geometry_msgs::TwistStamped>("jog_arm_server/delta_jog_cmds", 1);
    joint_delta_pub_ = n_.advertise<jog_msgs::JogJoint>("jog_arm_server/joint_delta_jog_cmds", 1);

    spinner_.start();
    ros::waitForShutdown();
  };

  const int arraySize = 100;// constant variable can be used to specify array size
  double vectorx[ arraySize ] = {};// initialize elements of array n to 0
  int resolution = 10;
  double derivativex = 0;
  double dx = 0; 
  int dt = 0;

private:

  ros::NodeHandle n_;
  ros::Subscriber joy_sub_;
  ros::Publisher twist_pub_, joint_delta_pub_;
  ros::AsyncSpinner spinner_;
  // Convert incoming joy commands to TwistStamped commands for jogging.
  void joyCallback(const jog_msgs::leapros::ConstPtr& msg)
 { 
    for ( int count = 0; count < arraySize; ++count ) {// store the values of poses
       vectorx[ count ] = msg->palmpos.x;
       if (count>resolution) {
           dx = vectorx[ count-1 ] - vectorx[ count-(resolution-1) ];
           dt = resolution;
           derivativex = dx / dt;
           ROS_ERROR("Hello %f", derivativex);

       }    

       if (count == arraySize) {
           count=0;  
       }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, you said "the output is always:" but you didn't say it's always what?

Comment: the output is always: 0       a ROS programmer said At the moment the loop in your callback is setting every element of vectorx to the most recent x value from the message, so your dx will anyways be zero. Do you know how to fix it? –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue 1: The log function ROS_ERROR is misused. You should pass a float instead of a string, otherwise, you will get an undefined behavior :

```
       ROS_ERROR("Hello %f", derivativex); // <-- there is no double quotes.
```

Issue 2: derivative of X is always 0 because of the assignment at the beginning of the for loop:

```
for ( int count = 0; count < arraySize; ++count ) {// store the values of poses

       //Could you please explain why the program needs this ???
       vectorx[ count ] = msg->palmpos.x; // <-- every element in vectorx is set to this values (const in each function call).

       if (count>resolution) {
           dx = vectorx[ count-1 ] - vectorx[ count-(resolution-1) ]; // is the same as (msg->palmpos.x - msg->palmpos.x) --> 0

           dt = resolution;
           derivativex = dx / dt;

           ROS_ERROR("Hello %f", derivativex);
       }    

       if (count == arraySize) {
           count = 0;  //<-- never get here because of count is always lesser than arraySize 
       }
}
```

I guess that you want to append msg->palmpos.x to the vectorx ? You should use std::vector for vectorx, it will be much easier.

Here is the modified version of your program, using std::vector :

```
//add this to your file
#include <vector>

//Your program body ...
//...

//As we are using C++, try to use C++ facilities if possible.
//const int arraySize = 100;// constant variable can be used to specify array size
//double vectorx[ arraySize ] = {};// initialize elements of array n to 0

std::vector<double> vectorx;

int resolution = 10;
int max_vector_size = 100; //keep 100 elements in the vectorx.
//...

// Convert incoming joy commands to TwistStamped commands for jogging.
void joyCallback(const jog_msgs::leapros::ConstPtr& msg)
{ 
     //store the x coordinate in the vectorx
     vectorx.push_back( msg->palmpos.x );

     if( vectorx.size() > resolution ){
         int id_back = vectorx.size() - 1;
         double dx = vectorx[id_back] - vectorx[ id_back - resolution ];
         double dt = resolution;

         derivativex = dx / dt;
         ROS_ERROR("Hello %f", derivativex);
     }

     while(vectorx.size() > max_vector_size ) {
         vectorx.erase( vectorx.begin() ); //remove the first element
     }

}//eof joyCallback
```

Comment: Hi sir, a ROS programmer said At the moment the loop in your callback is setting every element of vectorx to the most recent x value from the message, so your dx will anyways be zero. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: please take a look at this answer: https://answers.ros.org/question/311345/put-data-from-one-topic-into-an-dynamic-array-in-the-callback-function-and-do-calculation-in-ros/

Comment: I think my question is more about why can't put a certain number of different messages received one by one within a callback function into an array??? I reckon it is doable normally. Is it because a ROS callback function is very different???

Comment: @StevenSu: I updated my answer, please explain more about the method and the expected behavior.

Comment: I will explain more about my purpose. I am using a sensor called leap motion to track my hand and this sensor can read the position of your hand and send the hand position data( msg->palmpos) to this callback function. However, what I really need is the speed of my hand movement(derivativex = dx / dt).

Comment: Now I am going to answer you questions. 1.//Could you please explain why the program needs this ???vectorx[ count ] = msg->palmpos.x; //here I simply want to get a number of (in this case 100) different hand postion values(not a same one), then I can select part of these successive numbers to claculate my hand speed(derivativex = dx / dt).  So I am sure you are rigth about the mistake I made on this part: vectorx[ count ] = msg->palmpos.x; // <-- every element in vectorx is set to this values (const in each function call).

Comment: Can you please tell me how I can store these different values for my use instead of getting this const one only?

Comment: @StevenSu: I updated my answer with the codes you need, give me a feedback if it works.

Comment: Hi Sir, will give it a go as soon as possible. Just one more question about array and vector. I've been learned that one of the differences  between array and vector is the data we put in an array will keep their subscripts. However, the data we put in a vector just like puting data into a bag. When you retreive the data from the vecot, the sequence may be not the same oder we put them in before. To make the speed calculation accurate, for me, I think I need the data always in the certain oder and doesn't change the oder when I read them from array/vector.

Comment: This is why I acttauclly used array not vecot beofre. With you expertise, is this a problem? Do I have tp use array to keep the data oder(subscrpts) strictly? Or it doesn't matter at all that I use arrays or vectors. Thanks a million.

Comment: You should care for the performance once the expected behavior was found (your program worked first, then optimized later). For the performance, it can be better with std::list so that remove the first items will not move a whole 100 last items. But for your application, I doubt that it will be significant. Once the program works, you should try with std::list later, a way to move on in the C++ world.

Comment: Hi Sir, thanks a million. Will come back to you soon. Cheers